# Getting the row in a RowEnter event handler for a new row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a BindingSource. When I add a new row by clicking into it, the RowEnter event triggers. For some reason it is a CellEvent, not a RowEvent, so I don't get a Row property in the arguments. The RowIndex property is 0 (there's many rows - myDataGridView.Rows[0] is a wrong one). How do I get a reference to the actual Row, or the DataBoundItem behind it?

EDIT: It seems that I actually get two RowEnter events. The first one has RowIndex 0 and the second one has the correct one. The problem now is that I can't distinguish between the first of these events and a legitimate RowEnter thrown from the actual first row.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it by e.RowIndex

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1[i, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

Source : [DataGridView.RowEnter Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: He says that the RowIndex is 0 when it should not be. That's possibly some issue due to the bound collection.

Answer (score 1):

You issue possibly has something to do with peculiarities of data grid events sequencing and responsibility.

Taken from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/14c08e1f-7819-4687-8e4e-1df8632a8431/datagridviewselectionchanged-unexpected-behavior:

> DataGridView.RowEnter happens before DataGridView.SelectionChanged so
>   it is worthless for getting the latest data DataGridView.
>
> SelectionChanged appears to be the last event called on a row change. 
>   Please let me know if anyone knows of a later event.
>   DataGridView.SelectionChanged has the new
>   dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex if the user clicked on a new row in
>   the DataGridView
>
> DataGridView.SelectionChanged has the old
>   dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex if the program moves the row using:

```
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[0]; // Or whatever new row you want
    dataGridView1.Rows[3].Selected = true;
```

> And now  ... , SelectedRows[0].Index will return the new RowIndex on
>   either click or programmed move!!!

Or your problem actually stems from some problem in underlying binding and bound collection.